# Django: Group by foreign key then get max id from group

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to grab *each of the latest `message`s in all `conversation`s*. My `conversation` model has attributes `id` (primary key) and `user1` and `user2`, which are both foreign keys to a User model. My `message` model consists of a `conversation`(foreign key) and message primary key.

These both just return only the very latest message.

```
Message.objects.values('conversation').latest('id')
Message.objects.order_by('conversation').latest('id')
```

Any recommendations for getting this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# get a conversation

conversation = Conversation.objects.first()

# get last created message object in that conversation

last_message = Message.objects.filter(conversation=conversation).last()
```

Comment: What is your goal in the end? You want a queryset of all of the last sent messages in every conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Message.objects.filter(conversation=conversation).latest('id')
```